# Методы из Dictionary

Tags: c#, словари

```
public Dictionary<string, Func<List<string>, object>> operations = new Dictionary<string, Func<List<string>, object>>();
operations.Add("myComand", myMethod);
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, как реализовать такой словарь?

Comment: Вы же сами написали в вопросе его реализацию. В чем, собственно, затруднения ?

Comment: @Exodium не могу понять, как практически применить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
public class Commands<T>
{
    public readonly Dictionary<string, T> CommandDictionary =
        new Dictionary<string, T>();

    public void AddCommandToDictionary(string command,
        T action)
    {
        CommandDictionary.Add(command, action);
    }
}
```

Создаете объект:

```
Commands<Func<bool>> _commands = new Commands<Func<bool>> ();
```

И добавляете:

```
_commands.AddCommandToDictionary("input_command", () =>
{
    SomeUsefulFunction();

    return true;
});
```

И само использование:

```
Func<bool> cmd;
if (_commands.CommandDictionary.TryGetValue(input, out cmd))
{
    cmd();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Func<List<string>, object>` - делегат, который можно инициализировать  методом с прототипом, указанным в делегате [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx).

В вашем случае создавайте методы с прототипом:

```
public object MyMethod(List<string> input)
```

Далее присваивайте имена методов делегату и помещайте в словарь методом Dictionary.Add();